# How to create an ebook from an online blog

Tags: download, ebook, blogging, httrack

I'd like to create an ebook of an online blog in order to conveniently read through all of the posts offline.

How would one do that? Where do I start? Using HTTrack for download, maybe? And how to convert the html into an ebook?

Comment: where to ask then? what do you suggest, where can I get help?

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting more of trouble than it is worth. But you can use Sigil for creating ebooks. It may help to simplify source pages before you open then with sigil. And then you need to make sure that the images are in place etc. So this approach will take time, but you will learn more about CSS and HTML. A simple and crude way would be to copy blog page into libreoffice writer and save them to epub with writer2epub. Finally you could try to experiment with Calibre. Probably you will need to define book as HTML and then convert.

Comment: Calibre, as mentioned, is free and has adjustable formatting, including heuristic processing.

Comment: Yes it is pretty good. Still it is a bit of a chore, but there are "news recipes as well" I.e. you can set it to download from web and convert it to ebooks. Fiddly, if you have a single news source it might be worth while to make your own recipe. But not for faint hearted )